# Is there a software that will print large jigsaw patterns on letter sized sheets of paper?

Tags: jigsaw

I recently wanted to cut out a 3' spirograph using a jigsaw. I designed it in CAD and was eventually able to get something to work on a CNC router. In hindsight a jigsaw would have been just as good if not better. But I don't have a large format printer and CAD would've been a chore to use to print off all those different sheets.

Is there a software that will print large jigsaw patterns on letter sized sheets of paper?

Ideally the software would be specifically for this process and the sheets would fit together nicely for cutting with alignment marks or some such.

[image]

Comment: Can you tell me how this is off topic? I read the following in the help center, "Software that is used in the design of woodworking projects, such as SketchUp or AutoCAD, may also be considered a tool."

Comment: Just to be clear, the help center topic you quote is for specific questions about the usage of such software, e.g. "How can I bevel an edge in AutoCAD 2010?" (a specific answer that will never change). It is *not* meant to cover *asking* for software (non-specific opinions that generally will be different in the future). That said since this is such a specific use case I do recognize it as being borderline, but [we actually do have a specific site for software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: From the help center: "Software... may be considered a tool." then the line before that, "Tools may be general types of tools or specific products...", I am asking for a specific tool that to do a specific job that is a specific product. Your interpretation is incorrect or misguided. Also, I'm not sure who the "we" is in your last statement - are you stack exchange and I am not? Please use more patience and better judgement with questions in the future.

Comment: My interpretation is neither and that is covered multiple times elsewhere, but you are welcome to take it to meta or MSE if you need to be convinced. "We" includes you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Matthias Wandel on Woodgears wrote a program just for that. I haven't used it myself, but from his own use of this it looks like exactly what you are looking for. He is selling it for 22$, but there is also a free evaluation version:

https://woodgears.ca/bigprint/